# i have proble to count record from multiple field

Tags: sql, postgresql

the result of query is like this

```
SELECT d.icd_code,c.icd_verif2,c.icd_verif3, d.jenis_penyakit , COUNT(*) as totalapsien,e.nama as NamaPoly
FROM t_diagnosadanterapi c, icd d, m_poly e
WHERE c.status = '2' and  c.icd_verif = d.icd_code and c.kdpoly = e.kode
GROUP BY c.icd_verif, c.kdpoly, d.jenis_penyakit, e.nama, c.icd_verif2,c.icd_verif3, d.icd_code
ORDER BY c.icd_verif ASC
```

what i want is count field from icd_code to icd_code3 as jumlahpasien

Comment: what is icd_code to icd_code3?

Comment: i mean icd_verif o icd_verif3

Comment: Hi, @sena yudha it would be of much help if you can show us an example: what you are getting now as a result and what you want. Only two or three rows of data would be nice.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Proper `JOIN` syntax and reasonable table aliases should be requirements as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve:

> get `icd_verify` with values that are linked to your `icd_code`.

**in order to get this, we must:**

> ```
> 1. left join icd to include those with no matching verif.
> 2. use coalesce to to check values from verif 1 to 3
> 3. Need to change the way you join the tables, its quiet an old style.
> ```

```
select  d.icd_code, c.icd_verif2,c.icd_verif3, d.jenis_penyakit 
    , count(1) as totalapsien
    , sum(case when coalesce(c.icd_verif1, c.icd_verif2, c.icd_verif3, 0) != 0 then 1 else 0 end) as jumlahpasien
    , e.nama as NamaPoly
from t_diagnosadanterapi c 
left join icd d on c.icd_verif = d.icd_code
inner join m_poly e on c.kdpoly = e.kode
where c.status = '2' and   
group by c.icd_verif, c.kdpoly, d.jenis_penyakit, e.nama, c.icd_verif2, c.icd_verif3, d.icd_code
order by c.icd_verif asc
```